# use of "undertake"

Tags: meaning

I am not sure if the word "undertake" makes sense in this sentence:

> By giving credit, it means to always recognize the effort made by my
> colleagues, especially when they undertake a fair share of the project
> I am also working on.

Could you also briefly show me some examples of when to use *undertake*
more accurately? What is the difference between *be involved in* and
*undertake*?

Comment: When we say *X undertook [to do] Y*, we're ***usually*** implying that X made a deliberate ***choice*** and/or made a public ***commitment*** to Y. But your colleagues at work wouldn't normally choose to work with you on your project. Usually, your (shared) boss would ***assign*** them to help you (especially if you were struggling on your own).

Comment: @FumbleFingers i see, thank you

Comment: So you *might* decide to use "undertake" if your intended meaning was that your colleagues deliberately chose to spend time helping you (at the possible risk of neglecting their *own* assigned tasks). But not if they were just doing what the boss told them to do.

Answer (score 1):

I agree it doesn't feel like the right usage in this context.

I would prefer something like "when they contribute significantly to the project..."